# Norm of an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to calculate the infinite norm of  $\phi(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x(1-x) \mathrm{d}x$  with $f\colon[0;1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

But i don't know where to start.

Comment: By infinite norm you mean the operator norm wrt supremum norm on $C[0,1]$, right? If you do, can you bound $|\phi(f)|$ in term of $\|f\|_\infty$?

Comment: Hint : Use the integral form of the median value theorem.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the norm of $\phi$ as a linear functional from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, I tried to do that but I just have an inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall f \in C([0,1])$:

$$|\phi(f)| \le \int_0^1 |f(x)| x(1-x)dx \le \|f\|_{\sup} \int_0^1 (x-x^2)dx = \frac16 \|f\|_{\sup}$$

So $\|\phi\| \le 1/6$.

And for $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ (i.e. the constant function $1$), $\phi(f) = 1/6$, so $\|\phi\| = 1/6$.